# Setting up Express with Typescript to use top level async

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, package.json, tsconfig

I'm trying to setup my environment in such a way that I can use async in top level modules, and use the type of import statement seen in server.ts.

Using `type = module` in package.json allows me to do this, but now I am stuck with a `Cannot find module` error caused in server.ts

The solution to this is supposed to be adding .ts to the imported path, but this results in an unknown type exception.  The fix to this is supposed to be removing the `type=module` from package.json, but then I can't use the style of imports that I want

It feels like I'm going in circles here

### Server.ts

```
...
import purchaseRoute from './routes/purchaseRoute';

const connection = await createConnection({
    type: "mssql",
    host: "localhost",
    username: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "Investments"
});
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "investments",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
```

### purchaseRoute.ts

```
router.route('/').post(async(req, res) => {
    await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Purchase)
        .values(req.body);
})
export default router;
```

Comment: Can you show how you did export on routes?

Comment: @yogski  Added purchageRoute.ts, which shows how I am doing exports